# How to get Particular Country language from NSLocale in ios?

Tags: ios, localization, nslocale, country-codes

i am newbie here and New to iOS development, i want to get language of Particular country from `NSLocale` in iOs it i Possible or not?
i try this code but it give me all language but i want particular country language

```
NSArray *test = [NSLocale availableLocaleIdentifiers];
for (int i = 0; i < [test count]; i++) {
NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:[test objectAtIndex:i]];
NSString *language = [locale displayNameForKey:NSLocaleIdentifier value:[locale localeIdentifier]];
    NSLog(@"Langaugae %@",language);
}
```

i mean i want to get All Indian Language and any Other Country Language.
Thank You...

Comment: your coding is fine what the result u need

Comment: i need like as if i Select India then Only Indian Language like as Hindi,Tamil,Kannada,kashmiri...etc not any other country Language.

Comment: i am not sure you can get any single language for this

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Here i can't get Only Single language but i got All Language like as spanish,Italian etc... but i Want Language like as as i Select India as my Country then i want only Indian Language not other Country language like as Spanish italian i not want....

Answer (score 0):

```
You will have to add localization.string file per language and then add string in key-value pair in that file.

For more detail , you can refer this link.
1.http://www.raywenderlich.com/64401/internationalization-tutorial-for-ios-2014
2.http://smoothlocalize.com/tutorial1.php
3.http://www.ibabbleon.com/iphone_app_localization.html

You can see steps for adding localization file for language in below image screenshot
```

[image]

Comment: i not need localization for that i already do it for different language i want to get only particular Country language please read my question.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/readme.txt .
They provide lists of geographical information such as countries, languages, cities, locations, etc. In this case, you will need

```
http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/countryInfo.txt
http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/iso-languagecodes.txt
```

For India in countryInfo.txt

```
en-IN,hi,bn,te,mr,ta,ur,gu,kn,ml,or,pa,as,bh,sat,ks,ne,sd,kok,doi,mni,sit,sa,fr,lus,inc 1269750 CN,NP,MM,BT,PK,BD
```

Searching for hi in the ISO 639-1 column

```
hin hin hi  Hindi
```

The list is so large that you might want to import them to sqlite and remove unnecessary columns. I am not sure what you are working on exactly. we might come up with a better solution if you let us know more detail.

Answer (score 0):

```
var language = NSLocale.preferredLanguages[0]
print(NSLocale.current.languageCode)
```

This prints the language code. For example, "en" represents English.